# DateSerial vba stopped working after win10 installation

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code in excel vba that sort out data using the DateSerial function.

In other words I have a date (eg. 07.04.2019) and then that date is checked whether it can be proceed further in below code.

Unfortunately code is not working after win10 installation... maybe someone know how can I rebuild it?

```
ElseIf trdate >= DateSerial("2019", "03", "10") And trdate < DateSerial("2019", "04", "10") Then
```

Comment: *"is not working"* is no error description. It's like *"My car is not working"* well can be *anything* from missing wheels to empty battery. • Please read [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question. • You also need to show the relevant code part. Nobody here knows what `trdate` is and what type that variable is. So include the relevant information or better give a [mcve] (including input/output data example) to reproduce your issue.

Comment: meaning that the date avoids that elseif even though it should be considered to be within.

Comment: It is still not clear what `trdate` and which type this variable is. Please [edit] your question and either show the relevant code part including the variable declaration or explain which type the variable is and where the value comes from (eg if it comes from a cell please show the code how the variable gets its value). We cannot help you if we don't know that.

Comment: thanks @Pᴇʜ i think You have just helped me! you said which type this variable is and i was about to type it is string, but then i thought that i can store it as "date" and it worked. Coudl you please just tell me how can i clear the date variable as trdate = "" give me error. Thank you for helping.

Comment: That's actually what I assumed and why I asked for the type. Try `trdate = 0` that should work. Actually dates in Excel are just the count of days since 1900-01-01.

Comment: Many thanks for help!